# ASP.NET web app is stripping unprintable characters from text box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, barcode-scanner

I am writing a web application in ASP.NET that accepts a string from a 2D Barcode Reader using the 4.0 .NET Framework. I am developing on a Windows 7 64 bit box. The 2D Barcode has unprintable characters in it that must be maintained, specifically ascii codes 29 (group separator), 30 (Record Separator) and 4 (End of Transmission). These characters are being stripped.

When I scan a barcode into a .NET Windows application, the unprintable characters come through as expected.

When I copy the string from the Windows application and paste it into the ASP.NET web page textbox, the unprintable characters are stripped out again.

How can I get the web application to accept the unprintable characters?

Comment: You may have to html decode the textbox value.

Comment: Are you sure they are being stripped from the textbox? Or are they just not displayed and/or stripped on submit?

Comment: Stripped. On the code behind I am checking for those specific characters and they are not present using a button event.

Answer (score 0):

If you have special characters such as '<' and '>' you may want to encode the string to display those characters.

So you ll have to use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx

Comment: The problem is that the web page's textbox won't even allow those characters to be placed in it. If I copy "ABC DE" with the asc(30) between the "C" and the "D" and paste into the textbox, the asc(30) record separator is stripped. The text box ends up with just "ABCDE".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  What I had to do was when entering the string into the textbox, use "<=" instead of the single character version. Then on the backend, I replaced those instances with the Unicode values of the single character symbol, and when storing it in the sql database (make sure the fields are nvarchar, btw) use httputility.decode.  this got the values into the table correctly, and then were subsequently displayed correct (as one character.)

if your copy and paste is automated, you might have to include a encode, followed by a string.replace to change the Unicode value to the two character representation.